# How to create new columns based on over(partition by) another column?

Tags: sql, partition-by

I have a query that gives me this table:

```
| contract | sent_date |
| -------- | --------- |
|    a     |2020-01-02 |
|    a     |2020-01-02 |
|    b     |2020-01-02 |
|    a     |2020-01-03 |
|    c     |2020-01-03 |
|    b     |2020-01-04 |
|    a     |2020-01-05 |
|    a     |2020-01-05 |
```

I want to aggregate the count of each contract for each sent date. So the return table looks like:

```
| contract | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |
| -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|    a     |     2      |     1      |     0      |     2      |
|    b     |     1      |     0      |     1      |     0      |
|    c     |     0      |     1      |     0      |     0      |
```

Could anyone kindly give me some guidance how to form such query? Thank you.

Comment: The way to go is to use a pivot clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the list of dates you want for the columns, use conditional aggregation:

```
select contract,
       sum(case when sent_date = '2020-01-02' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when sent_date = '2020-01-03' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when sent_date = '2020-01-04' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when sent_date = '2020-01-05' then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by contract;
```

If the list is based on the data, then you need dynamic SQL.  The exact syntax depends on the database you are using.